# My location manager made my application crash?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-location

I'm a newbie at android, and I have trouble with LocationManager.
I try to give comment almost everything and the application is Showing a maps. which means I already get a key from google api and anything else works.
Then i want to get my current location.

I try to uncomment these

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

and I get force close message from my device..

here's my activity

```
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.location.Criteria;
 import android.location.Location;
 import android.location.LocationManager;

 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

 import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;


 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
  private GoogleMap mMap;
  LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
  public Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
  public String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria,true);
  public Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
  public Double latid = myLocation.getLatitude();
  public Double longi = myLocation.getLongitude();
  public LatLng Coba = new LatLng(latid,longi);
  protected Context context;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(Coba, 16));

        }    
}
```

Logcat?

> 12-28 16:01:38.830: E/Launcher(268): setWindowOpaque()
>   12-28 16:01:42.630: E/UinboxLogger(3310): [UinboxReceiver] onReceive() >> Context is >android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext@40523808
>   12-28 16:01:44.010: E/AndroidRuntime(3337): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   12-28 16:01:44.010: E/AndroidRuntime(3337): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hellomap/com.example.hellomap.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
>   12-28 16:01:44.010: E/AndroidRuntime(3337):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1573)
>   12-28 16:01:44.010: E/AndroidRuntime(3337):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
>   12-28 16:01:44.010: E/AndroidRuntime(3337):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
>   12-28 16:01:44.010: E/AndroidRuntime(3337):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
>   12-28 16:01:44.010: E/AndroidRuntime(3337):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   12-28 16:01:44.010: E/AndroidRuntime(3337):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
>   12-28 16:01:44.010: E/AndroidRuntime(3337):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
>   12-28 16:01:44.010: E/AndroidRuntime(3337):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   12-28 16:01:44.010: E/AndroidRuntime(3337):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>   12-28 16:01:44.010: E/AndroidRuntime(3337):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
>   12-28 16:01:44.010: E/AndroidRuntime(3337):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
>   12-28 16:01:44.010: E/AndroidRuntime(3337):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   12-28 16:01:44.010: E/AndroidRuntime(3337): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
>   12-28 16:01:44.010: E/AndroidRuntime(3337):     at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:3536)
>   12-28 16:01:44.010: E/AndroidRuntime(3337):     at com.example.hellomap.MainActivity.(MainActivity.java:30)
>   12-28 16:01:44.010: E/AndroidRuntime(3337):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
>   12-28 16:01:44.010: E/AndroidRuntime(3337):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
>   12-28 16:01:44.010: E/AndroidRuntime(3337):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
>   12-28 16:01:44.010: E/AndroidRuntime(3337):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1565)
>   12-28 16:01:44.010: E/AndroidRuntime(3337):     ... 11 more
>   12-28 16:01:44.020: E/(171): Dumpstate > /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
>   12-28 16:01:49.609: E/Launcher(268): setWindowOpaque()
>   12-28 16:01:49.679: E/Launcher(268): MTP-LAUNCHER: media scanning not yet finished.

Comment: please provide crash logs.

Comment: post the logcat and xml  .. please

Comment: @Abdullah Shoaib : I try to get a crash log here..

Comment: @Abdullah Shoaib : 12-28 15:51:46.400: E/AndroidRuntime(2900): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hellomap/com.example.hellomap.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()

Answer (score 0):

use in xml

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/crntlocation"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

In activity

```
SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            googleMap = fm.getMap();
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

and
```

// Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you are trying to initiate

```
      LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)
getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

before onCreate method is called.

//Initiate these components in onCreate()

```
 LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
  public String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria,true);
  public Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
  public Double latid = myLocation.getLatitude();
  public Double longi = myLocation.getLongitude();
  public LatLng Coba = new LatLng(latid,longi);
```

Your mMap can return null, use Try & catch block.

Comment: it still show some error when i put that inside onCreate method

Comment: Learn how to find error using Logcat, Please post the Logcat stacktrack.